# IF and ELSIF in the PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

I have this code that I write, but the problem is that I cannot use the `ELSEIF` statement in there and I don't know why, and Oracle Developer doesn't let me to execute it.

Is anyone able to help me with this please ?

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR p_cursor IS
    SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE
      FROM PRODUCT
  ORDER BY PRICE ;
  p_row p_cursor%ROWTYPE ;
  p_name VARCHAR2(30) ;
  p_price NUMBER ;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD('Product Name', 25, ' ') || 'Price Status');
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD('-', 24, '-') || RPAD(' -', 14, '-'));
  FOR p_row IN p_cursor
    LOOP
    p_name := p_row.PRODUCT_NAME;
    p_price := p_row.PRICE ;

    IF p_price < 5  THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' Low');
    END IF;
    IF p_price > 5 AND p_price < 20 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' Medium');
    END IF;
    IF p_price > 20 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' High');
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

I want to have something like this

```
IF p_price < 5  THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' Low');
ELSEIF p_price > 5 AND p_price < 20 THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' Medium');
ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' High');
END IF;
```

Comment: You didnt got any error message?

Comment: Your code doesn't cover the case where `p_price = 5`.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is wrong - in pl/SQL it's not `ELSEIF`, it's `ELSIF`, without the second E:

```
IF p_price < 5  THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' Low');
ELSIF p_price > 5 AND p_price < 20 THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' Medium');
ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(p_name, 25, ' ') || ' High');
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I didn't know, and I though that's the correct way and didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: I always find it funny the "correct" syntax just *has* to be a typo where someone left out the 'E' back in the day and it was never caught.  I mean come on, 'ELSIF" ?!.

Comment: PL/SQL has its roots in the Ada language, and that's the syntax for the IF statement in Ada.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ELSIF`, and not `ELSEIF`. 
 
For example:

```
vcValue VARCHAR2(10) := 'ABC';

IF vcValue = 'ABC' THEN
    -- vcValue = 'ABC';
ELSIF vcValue = 'DEF' THEN
    -- vcValue = 'DEF';
ELSE
    -- vcValue is not 'ABC' or 'DEF';
END IF;
```

Here is a link with docuentation about the IF, ELSIF, ELSE statement: [Link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php)